# Invalid hook call when component is translation file

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have 2 translation files for `en.tsx` and `es.tsx`. Each file has an object with all of our strings (it's an old repo so there are also components that are returned).

Here is what that looks like:

```js
import Link from 'component-library/ui/atoms/Link'

en: {
  ...
  errorMessage: (
    <span>
      Example error{' '}
      <Link isInline to={routes.EXAMPLE_ERROR_ROUTE}>
        Find your User ID
      </Link>
      message.
    </span>
  ),
  ...
```

We are currently updating our repo from React 16 to 18. When upgrading we are receiving an error in our redux files and other non-component files:

```bash
console.error
      Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
      1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
      2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
      3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
      See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
```

It seems we may have duplicate React copies. When I follow the instructions React provides:

```js
// Add this in node_modules/react-dom/index.js
window.React1 = require('react');

// Add this in your component file
require('react-dom');
window.React2 = require('react');
console.log(window.React1 === window.React2);
```

I get `false` in the console. However, we aren't using `npm link` and not entirely sure what the process is to fix. Do I go into `<project-path>/node_modules/lib` then run `npm link`? Either way I don't even know what application to do this in.

When I ran `npm ls react` several of our modules are using React, but looks like all of the modules are using the same version. However, this is one `react@18.2.0`, which you can see in the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: first, check your lock file, whether you have just single instances of `react` and `react-dom` and that their versions are the same